# How to create a form that contains only a progress bar in c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I want to create a form with a progress bar in it. The form doesn't have any button. It has only a progress bar to show percentage of process progress.
sorry but I can not post image of the form.
Please tell me How can I do this.

Comment: More info needed. Are you wanting to create it programatically or using the form designer????

Comment: what is preventing you just place a single control on a form ?

Comment: I want to create it programatically.

Comment: Can anyone sending an example of it to me?  
iman.yasouriATgmail

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create it programatically, then you could just recreate the code that the designer pre-builds for you, and tweak it to your needs, like so;

```
this.progressLoadingBar = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
this.progressLoadingBar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 227);
this.progressLoadingBar.Name = "progressLoadingBar";
this.progressLoadingBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);
this.progressLoadingBar.TabIndex = 9;
this.Controls.Add(this.progressLoadingBar);
```

Here. just make sure "this" is the context of your form. if you wanted to tweak further, use the intellisense and look through your options, or else google is your best friend, the MSDN page can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx